# Add xml element immediately after another element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml

```
  <request_scope>
     <valuation_currency>GBP</valuation_currency>
     <fund_code_type_required>FUND1</fund_code_type_required>
     <valuation_request type="Current"/>
     <valuation_request type="Surrender"/>
     <fund_breakdown_request>yes</fund_breakdown_request>
  </request_scope>
```

and I want an xslt that adds element **intermediary** immediately after **fund_code_type_required**
only if **intermediary** does not exist. So to be

```
   <request_scope>
      <valuation_currency>GBP</valuation_currency>
      <fund_code_type_required>FUND1</fund_code_type_required>
      <intermediary></intermediary>
      <valuation_request type="Current"/>
      <valuation_request type="Surrender"/>
      <fund_breakdown_request>yes</fund_breakdown_request>
   </request_scope>
```

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just match `fund_code_type_required` when it's a child of `request_scope` and doesn't have a sibling `intermediary`. Output a copy of `fund_code_type_required` and add the new element after...

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" expand-text="yes">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="request_scope[not(intermediary)]/fund_code_type_required">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <intermediary/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94humqD